# Why error occurred while creating GIN index?

Tags: postgresql

I've created a table to investigate text searching and using GIST and GIN indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  the_text text,
  CONSTRAINT test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

And added some random values:

```
insert into test values (generate_series(1,100000), md5(random()::text))
```

And wanted to create GIN index:

```
create index on test using gin(the_text);
```

But I had an error:

> ERROR:  data type text has no default operator class for access method "gist"

Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 36):

You need to enable `:btree_gin` or `:btree_gist` as well, since it's some sort of dependency for CREATE INDEX to work. The following worked for me and fixed the message `ERROR: data type text has no default operator class for access method "gin"`

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gin;
CREATE INDEX index_email_gin ON users USING GIN (email);
```

Comment: Why is `btree_gin` needed? On PG15, I was able to create a GIN index using only `pg_trgm`.

Answer (score 11):

For [full text](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/textsearch-tables.html) search use:

```
CREATE INDEX test_gin_idx ON test USING gin (to_tsvector('english', the_text));
```

For trigram search you can use `pg_trgm` extension

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
CREATE INDEX test_the_text_gin_idx ON test USING GIN (the_text gin_trgm_ops);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, some other script created the extension in a non-standard schema, thus the gin_trgm_ops was not being found.
I added `ALTER EXTENSION pg_trgm SET SCHEMA pg_catalog;` to my script and it worked.
Hope that helps someone.